# String.join() vs. .toString() in Apex

Tags: apex

In apex, I have a `Set<String>` and further in the code, I'm converting this Set to String using `.toString()` method.

```
Set<String> fields = new Set<String>();
String query = 'SELECT ' + fields.toString().replace('}', '').replace('{', '') + ' FROM Account';
```

It was working fine, till I added a new field to the Set and then, instead of all fields in the query, it printed the fields like:

```
'field1, field2, field3, field4, ...'
```

So these 3 dots is making problem.
I've replace `.toString()` with `String.join(new List<String>(fields),', ')` and now it's working again.
But I didn't understand the problem. Is there any limit for toString() characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Object.toString()` is unreliable in Apex. Objects that do not explicitly call out `toString()` as a feature use a particular `toString()` that was designed to be output in a debug log. Even worse, this default behavior can come from string concatenation on classes that *do* have a documented `toString()`.

```
System.debug(''+Blob.valueOf('Hello World')); // Blob[11]
System.debug(Blob.valueOf('Hello World').toString()); // Hello World
```

You'll find these kinds of problems all over the place. For example, Date and DateTime have the same `toString()`:

```
Date today = Date.today();
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
String todayString = today.toString();
String nowString = now.toString();
System.debug(todayString); // 2024-01-01 00:00:00
System.debug(nowString); // 2024-01-01 01:02:03
```

`Map`, `List`, and `Set` all suffer from this same condition. If the default `toString()` is called, they will truncate themselves after a few values.

In contrast, `String.join()` is 100% reliable. It will always write out all the values, no matter how long the string ends up being (up to heap size limits). You should always use `String.join()` when possible to ensure consistent behavior in regards to how the string will turn out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you've encountered is a known behavior in Apex when using the `toString()` method on collections, such as `Set<String>`. When the string representation of a collection reaches a certain length, Salesforce abbreviates the output by inserting ellipses `(...)` towards the end. This is to prevent excessive memory usage or potential performance issues with very large collections.

Your initial approach directly converted the Set to a string and manipulated it to remove the curly braces, which are part of the default output format for sets in `toString()`. As your set grew, the abbreviation issue manifested, indicating Salesforce's internal limit was reached, causing it to truncate the string representation.

Switching to `String.join(new List<String>(fields), ', ')` resolved the issue because this method explicitly joins the elements of the collection into a single string without adding extra formatting or risking abbreviation. `String.join()` is designed for precisely this scenario, where a predictable and complete string representation is needed, without the addition of formatting characters like braces or the risk of encountering the ellipsis abbreviation.

This approach is particularly useful for dynamically constructing SOQL queries or similar tasks where an accurate representation of collection elements as a string is required.

It's worth noting that Salesforce documentation doesn't explicitly state the character limit for the `toString()` abbreviation, likely because it could be subject to Salesforce's internal implementation details or limits, which may change. Therefore, for tasks requiring the full representation of collection elements as a string, methods like `String.join()` are recommended.

Comment: Thanks, completely understood :)

Comment: @Ghazal This answer is debatably incorrect. We usually recommend waiting a day before accepting any answer, because sometimes another answer might come along.

Comment: `toString` is used to form debug log statements. This means that every object has some default implementation, so you're never quite sure what you're going to get until you test them out. Collections indeed auto-truncate, dates output in datetime form, blobs output `Blob[size]` unless you explicitly call `toString`, and so on. One definitely shouldn't depend on this to work "correctly" for most objects.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks. I will keep this in my mind:)